# Is it possible to scoll a LinearLayout

Tags: android, scroll, textview, android-linearlayout

I'm filling programmatically a `LinearLayout` with some `TextView`s using the `addView()` method.

Is it even possible to let a `LinearLayout` scroll? Is there a widget that I could use instead? I tried quite a few but nothing worked.

I found a few websites that recommended to use a `TextView` to create a scrolling area, but a `TextView` won't take "subviews", right?

Thanks in advance!
S.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want to put your `LinearLayout` inside a `ScrollView`.